# After deployed values are not fetch and not insert in to tables using JNDI connection

Tags: java, web, struts, jndi

My project is on `struts1.3`,`JNDI datasource connection`, `tomcat 6` .the problem is that on local box it runs properly i.e, fetching and inserting values into database. But as soon as i deploy on the server as a `war` where server config is(linux red hat,tomcat5),its not working
and the value is showing as `NULL`.

Where as for debugging I use `JDBC` code in one jsp page and that page perfectly getting all the values from table.

What to do...?

Comment: are you getting some exception in the code or in the log?